# AutoresizesForKeyboard and Multiple TTTextEditors

Tags: objective-c, three20

When creating a form using three20 components with the methodology found in [this example code](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTCatalog/Classes/TableControlsTestController.m), there are some strange behaviors with multiple TTTextEditors and UITextFields.  Sometimes the fields disappear when touching the next one to enter text.  After scouring for a solution, I found someone else with the same problem.  Thought it would be useful to see [it in his/her words](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/cbc20900dd792d4e/74485d3b754bf90f?lnk=gst&q=autoresizesForKeyboard#74485d3b754bf90f).

My code hardly differs from the example given with three20 so I suspect it is a bug with the library.  I too have tried `self.autoresizesForKeyboard = NO;` but find that it makes typing in a hidden (by the keyboard) field impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the few lines of code to fix it!

http://github.com/noahmiller/three20/commit/577af26ed4cd636f152e2321fdc6ab08787452af

I found this link via this message 
https://github.com/facebook/three20/issuesearch?state=open&q=autoresize#issue/139